# How can we change data from a 2D matrix to a 1D matrix?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to list data points, which are in cells FQ121 to FW151 (2D matrix) and I would like to list everything in one column (1D matrix). I have an 'Output' sheet where I am trying to show my results and a 'Daily Forecast' sheet where the data sits.

Again, how can I show, in one column in my 'Output' sheet, the range of values from FQ121 to FW151, which is 31 rows by 7 columns. I need to use functions and not VBA code, as the client will probably not understand any kind of VBA solution.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: This is Excel 365 MSO Ver. 2111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using INDEX and SEQUENCE:

By Row:

```
=INDEX(FQ121:FW151,SEQUENCE(31*7,,1,1/7),MOD(SEQUENCE(31*7,,0),7)+1)
```

[image]

By Column:

```
=INDEX(FQ121:FW151,MOD(SEQUENCE(31*7,,0),31)+1,SEQUENCE(31*7,,1,1/31))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfect!!  Saves me a lot of time!!  Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Nice. I like the use of a fractional *step* parameter in `SEQUENCE`.